# Is it true that $(1+\varepsilon)\pi(x+y)\ge\pi(x)+\pi(y)$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Recently I was going through Udrescu's result concerning the inequality $\pi(x)+\pi(y)\ge\pi(x+y)$ which states that ($\pi(x)$ denotes the [prime counting function](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjOi_-q3JXGAhWC2KYKHeMMAAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPrime-counting_function&ei=v-CAVY6wFYKxmwXjmYAo&usg=AFQjCNFUJXlUM9E37fBU8kh6K6WiqjKWYA&bvm=bv.96041959,d.dGY)),

> For all $\varepsilon>0$ and any $x,y\ge 17$ with $x+y\ge 1+e^{4\left(1+1/\varepsilon\right)}$ we have, $$\pi(x+y)\le (1+\varepsilon)(\pi(x)+\pi(y))$$

So, I was wondering whether it can be shown that,

> For all $\varepsilon>0$ and for all sufficiently large $x$ and $y$ we have, $$(1+\varepsilon)\pi(x+y)\ge\pi(x)+\pi(y)$$

Can anyone at least give me a sketch of the proof?

Comment: Your statement is not implied by the above result. The point is that at least one of $x,y$ must be going to infinity as $\epsilon$ gets smaller. In other words, your "sufficiently" large could potentially be $x=\infty$. The best you can say is for any finite collection $\{\epsilon_1,\cdots,\epsilon_n\}$...

Comment: This strikes me as being highly unlikely.

Comment: @AlexR.: I didn't say that my statement is implied by Udrescu's result. They are two different problems indeed. I only said that while going through the result I "was wondering" whether my result also can be shown.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes. It seems so to me too. My intuition tells me that the "for all sufficiently large $x,y$"-requirement is too strong for the inequality to be true. Why do you think that the inequality is unlikely?